# Recommended way to store data from socket.io connected clients?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In `socket.io`, I need to store all the data received from the client, which are x,y based points.

The database is on another server as the node is within a cluster.

I know that I will store the point at the database server in a non-blocking function, but there are about hundred or even thousand of points received from connected clients.

What would be the optimized way to handle such a case?

EDIT

My concern is not about the database type, but about latency time for each storage operation, as the database is on another server, while the socket.io (where clients data recieved) is on another clustered server.

Comment: This is pretty broad for Stackoverflow. Any of the leading databases will do fine: postgresql, mysql, mongodb, other nosql ones, etc. It more depends on how you want to query the data later. Make sure to use a db with geospatial support, for example, if you want to do geometric queries. (postgres and mongo support this, others too)

Comment: Kindly check edit above

Comment: Did you found a good solution ?